# Nodejs: Read and write to a memory address

Tags: node.js, virtual-memory

How can I write and read a value in specific **memory** address? Is it possible to do that in **Nodejs**?

For example if a value is stored at 0x16FB8388(user-space), Then is it possible to fetch the value stored here through the Nodejs? or even write there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't virtual memory supposed to be _virtual_? Or do you somehow know that on address `0x16FB8388` in your NodeJS process there's something that you need to read or write?

Comment: @robertklep, I think you have no idea what does Memory/Virtual Memory mean... I'm talking about *absolute memory address*

Comment: Do you mean _physical_ memory address?

Comment: physical address = virtual address + base. Im talking about virtual address which is in user-space

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what exactly it is that you're trying to achieve, because it doesn't really make a lot of sense to me. Why do you need to access a particular memory address? What does the example address 0x16FB8388 contain within the context of the Node.js process? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best answer, but [`ref`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ref) tries to solve your problem. At least for Buffers.